# Where to configure logging?

Tags: python, logging, project

I'm wondering where to configure and initialize stuff related with logging module?

For example I writing some class and I want to log some info while method will be executed. Should I configure logging in **init** or above class on the top of module:

```
# LOGGING STUFF <--- Should be here ? 

class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self):
        # class stuff
        # LOGGING STUFF <--- Or should be here ? 

    def some_method(self):
        # method stuff
        # LOGGING SOME INFO    

    def some_method2(self):
        # method stuff
        # LOGGING SOME INFO
```

What is the best practice ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The logging package serves two purposes, assisting the author to produce logs and assisting the user to consume logs. You might perform both those roles but thinking about them separately will help you write clean, understandable code.

### Authors Concerns

Author should instantiate the logger at the right level:

- Package logger should go in the packages `__init__` file. Note the use of `__name__`, it'll resolve to `SomePackage`:

  ```
    import logging
    package_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
  ```
- Module logger at the top of your module. Note the power of `__name__`! Here it'll resolve to `SomePackage.SomeModule`.

  ```
    import logging
    module_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
  ```
- Class level logger could go at the top of the class definition. Note the awesome power of `__name__` enhanced with getLogger and `__qualname__`! The loggers name will be `SomePackage.SomeModule.SomeClass`. Also, note the underscore in `_class_logger` to signal that it is for internal use.:

  ```
    class SomeClass:
        _class_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__).getChild(__qualname__)
  ```
- Instance logger in the classes `__init__`. Use ID to produce a unique identifier. Note the stupend... you get the idea. Logger name will be `SomePackage.SomeModule.SomeClass.<large_unique_number>`:

  ```
    class SomeClass:
        def __init__(self):
            self._instance_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__).getChild(self.__class__.__name__).getChild(str(id(self)))
  ```

The names may not suit your application. For instance you may want an instance logger that is derived from one of it's instantiating args. However, you should still aim to get a grip on your logger at the right level.

### Users Concerns

It's the Users job to configure handlers. Generally, the author will have ensured that no handlers will be active by default. `logging.basicConfig` will dump all log records of level warning and above to stderr.

```
import SomePackage
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
```

Remember you can use logging.getLogger() to access the same loggers that the author defined.

```
from SomePackage import SomeModule
import logging

"""
module_logger debug to a file. Will capture all 
child loggers as well if used i.e class_logger and 
instance_logger
"""
h = logging.FileHandler('debug')
h.setLevel('DEBUG')
SomeModule.module_logger.addHandler(h)

"""
class_logger warning to stderr. Will capture all child loggers
as well if used i.e instance_logger Note: No need to import
SomeClass to access it's logger as Logger keeps track of them in
a dictionary. Typically the prefered approach if your not
actually using the class.
"""
h = logging.StreamHandler()
getLogger('SomePackage.SomeModule.SomeClass').addHandler(h)
```

If you're debugging your own modules by calling them directly, you probably have a `def main()` and they should go in there. This ensures a package user won't get unexpected log files or consoles messages.

### Extra Marks

If using loggers at multiple levels, deriving from existing ones is more pythonic.

```
module_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class SomeClass:
    _class_logger = module_logger.getChild(__qualname__)

    def __init__(self):
        self._instance_logger = self._class_logger.getChild(str(id(self)))
```

Comment: Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same [id()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) value. [uuid4()](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/uuid.html?highlight=uuid#uuid.uuid4) is a better way of obtaining a unique identifier for the life of the program run.

Comment: I have a package with module logging. This package is used in a function `def main()` under which I configure the logger. What is best practice for a script that wraps `main()` and calls it multiple times?